# How do i change the position of a UITableViewCell in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Not by doing the following, find out.

```
self.tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath,toIndexPath: NSIndexPath(index:0))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A indexPath for a tableView should use

```
NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
```

in this case.

The tableview does need information regarding your section.